# How to prevent parallel execution of asynchronous init method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to preload a search index in JavaScript as soon as the page is loaded, so that the user may not have to wait for it to be build. I know JavaScript is single threaded and a lock is normally not required, but I am not sure if the following code is sufficient:

```
class Index
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.index = null;
  }

  async init()
  {
    this.index = await queryDatabase();
  }

  async search(input)
  {
    if(!this.index) {await this.init();}
    return this.index.query(input);
  }
}

Index index = new index();
index.init(); // preload
myButton.addEventListener("click",console.log(index.search()));
```

Can it happen that a user clicks on myButton before init() is finished and that init is called twice? If not, how can I prevent that in the best way?

Comment: You could pass `myButton` into `init()` and add the event listener only after the query returns.

Comment: `this.index = await queryDatabase(); myButton.addEventListener(...);`

Comment: `myButton.addEventListener("click",console.log(index.search()));` Is a problematic. You're binding the return value of `console.log` as the event listener. Meaning, whatever is currently logged to your console, has nothing to do with whether somebody clicked that button.

Comment: @Yoshi and the fact `index.search` is `async` make it even worse I believe. (unless OP really want to log `Promise`)

Comment: @yoshi: Sorry, I made a mistake when simplifying my real code to the example, I just wanted to print the search results. This should be an asynchronous arrow function that waits for the results and then prints them.

Answer (score 5):

`init()` is `async` , it returns a promise, you can add the event listener after querying the database :

```
class Index {
  constructor() {
    this.index = null;
  }

  async init() {
    this.index = await queryDatabase();
  }

  async search(input) {
    if (!this.index) {
      await this.init();
    }
    return this.index.query(input);
  }
}

Index index = new index();

index.init().then(() => {
  // add the event listener after the init
  myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   console.log(index.search()) 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Same as @Taki (upvote his) but using async/await syntax 100%.

IIFE syntax : https://jack.ofspades.com/es6-iife-with-fat-arrow-functions/

```
class Index {
  constructor() {
    this.index = null;
  }

  async init() {
    this.index = await queryDatabase();
  }

  async search(input) {
    // should never happend
    if (this.index === null) {
      await this.init();
    }

    return this.index.query(input);
  }
}

const index = new index();

(async() => {
  await index.init();

  // add the event listener after the init
  myButton.addEventListener('click', console.log(index.search()));
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also init it in constructor.

```
class Index
{
  constructor(){this.index = queryDatabase();}
  async search(input){
    return (await this.index).query(input);
  }
}
```

---

or simply change `search` be normal function and just assume the user would call `init()` and wait for it.

```
class Index
{
  constructor(){this.index = null;}
  async init(){this.index = await queryDatabase();}

  search(input)
  {
    //just assume the `init()` is called.
    return this.index.query(input);
  }
}
```

---

*you can actually make the constructor return a `Promise<Index>` and instantiate it like `let index = await new Index` but it's not widely used and may cause confusion. (An alternative would be factory method)

** also note that your implementation is not safe, one can easily call `search` multiple times and you (wrongly) calls `init` multiple times. (which is valid use case like `Promise.All(search(A),search(B))`)

Answer (score 1):

The above two answers are "spot on."

I would also like to offer the opinion that I do *not* recommend the bit of code that now appears in the `search()` method:

```
 if(!this.index) {await this.init();}
```

Instead, "just make sure that it *is* ready-to-use before you install event-listeners and so forth which will attempt to use it."

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you really need that `class` infrastructure for this.  If `Index` is as simple as that, you might be better to just create the `search` function with access to the Promise returned by `queryDatabase`.  This version does that, and demonstrates with a progress bar that simulates how long until `queryDatabase` returns.  You can click the search button once or more before it returns, and the output will be shown only when the data is available.

`queryDatabase` is faked with the object `{foo: 42, bar: 99, baz: 7}`, returning values for `"foo"`, `"bar"`, and `"baz"`.

```js
const search = ((index) => 
  async (input) => (await index) .query (input)
) (queryDatabase ())

myButton .addEventListener ('click', async () => {
  log (await search (getTerm ()))
})
```

```css
.bar {border: 1px solid #666; height: 15px; width: 100%;} .bar .in {animation: fill 5s linear 1; height: 100%; background-color: blue;} @keyframes fill {0% {width: 0%;} 100% {width: 100%;}} select, button {margin-left: 1em;}
```

```html
<p><label>Search Term <select id="term"><option>foo</option><option>bar</option><option>baz</option></select></label><button id="myButton">Search</button></p><div class="bar"><div class="in"></div></div><pre id="output">Output:</pre>
<script>
const queryDatabase = () => new Promise ((res) => setTimeout(() => res ({query: key => ({foo: 42, bar: 99, baz: 7})[key]}), 5000))
const myButton = document.getElementById ('myButton')
const term = document.getElementById ('term')
const output = document.getElementById ('output')
const getTerm = () => term.options[term.selectedIndex].value
const log = (msg) => output.innerHTML += '\n' + msg 
</script>
```

You could spell this out more explicitly with something like:

```
const makeSearch = () => {
  const index = queryDatabase()
  return async (input) => (await index) .query (input)
}

const search = makeSearch()

myButton .addEventListener ('click', async () => {
  const results = await search (getTerm ())
  log (results)
})
```

But either way, this seems simpler than a class which will presumably only be instantiated once.